# Renaming file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rename, file-rename

I'm trying to rename the files in a folder, but I can't. This is my code:

```
import os

directory = r"C:\Users\jhonatta-silva\Downloads"

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.startswith("PBI"):
        os.rename(file, file.strip("0123456789 "))
```

and I receive an error like this:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'PBIItemsResults132.csv' -> 'PBIItemsResults132.csv'
```

Comment: `file` doesn't have the directory name in it. Use `os.path.join(directory, file)`

Comment: `os.listdir()` returns file names, not paths. You have to include the path when you rename.

Comment: could you give me an example? @RandomDavis

Comment: It didn't work, could you give me an example? @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the directory to the names in the `os.rename()` call.

```
import os

directory = r"C:\Users\jhonatta-silva\Downloads"

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.startswith("PBI"):
        os.rename(os.path.join(directory, file), os.path.join(file.strip("0123456789 ")))
```

Instead of using `os.listdir()` and then `file.startswith()`, you can use `glob.glob()` to just process files beginning with that prefix. It returns full paths when the argument is a full path.

```
import os, glob

directory = r"C:\Users\jhonatta-silva\Downloads"

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "PBI*")):
    os.rename(file, file.rstrip("0123456789 "))
```

Comment: Worked, thank you!  

Why when I run the code my files are excluded? I just want to rename, it.

Comment: `startswith` is case-sensitive. Do they start with `PBI` or `pbi`? You could use `if file.upper().startswith("PBI")` to do a case-insensitive comparison.